# Why is my C++ array printing the same values?

Tags: c++, linux, process, operating-system, pipe

I am working on a code where it will do Linux command piping. Basically in my code, it will parse the user input command, then run it using the `execvp` function.

However, to do this, I would need to know the command, as well as its parameters. I have been trying to get the parsing to work correctly, however, it seems that when I do a test case, the output from both of the arrays that store their respective programs is the same. The commands/parameters are stored in a char array called `prgname1` and `prgname2`.

For instance, if I were to run my program with the parameter "`ps aux | grep [username]`", then the output of prgname1[0] and prgname2[0] are both [username]. They are supposed to be `ps` and `grep`, respectively.

Can anyone take a look at my code and see where I might be having an error which is causing this?

Thanks!

```
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>

#define MAX_PARA_NUM 5
#define MAX_COMMAND_LEN 1024

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
char *prgname1[MAX_PARA_NUM], *prgname2[MAX_PARA_NUM];
char command[MAX_COMMAND_LEN];
int pfd[2];
pipe(pfd);
pid_t cid1, cid2;

char *full = argv[1];
char str[MAX_COMMAND_LEN];
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
int k = 0;
int ind = 0;
while (ind < strlen(full)) {
    if (full[ind] == ' ') {
        strncpy(command, str, i);
        cout << command << endl;
        prgname1[j] = command;
        j++;
        i = 0;
        ind++;
    }
    else {
        str[i] = full[ind];
        i++;
        ind++;
    }

    if(full[ind] == '|') {
        i = 0;
        j = 0;
        ind+=2;
        while (ind < strlen(full)) {
            if (full[ind] == ' ') {
                strncpy(command, str, i);
                cout << command << endl;
                prgname2[j] = command;
                j++;
                i = 0;
                ind++;
            }
            else {
                str[i] = full[ind];
                i++;
                ind++;
            }
            if (ind == strlen(full)) {
                strncpy(command, str, i);
                cout << command << endl;
                prgname2[j] = command;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

    // test output here not working correctly
cout << prgname1[0] << endl;
cout << prgname2[0] << endl;

// exits if no parameters passed
if (argc != 2) {
    cout << "Usage:" << argv[0] << endl;
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

// exits if there is a pipe error
if (pipe(pfd) == -1) {
    cerr << "pipe" << endl;
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
cid1 = fork();  // creates child process 1

// exits if there is a fork error
if (cid1 == -1 || cid2 == -1) {
    cerr << "fork";
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
// 1st child process executes and writes to the pipe
if (cid1 == 0) {
    char **p = prgname1;
    close(1);   // closes stdout
    dup(pfd[1]);    // connects pipe output to stdout
    close(pfd[0]);  // closes pipe input as it is not needed
    close(pfd[1]);  // closes pipe output as pipe is connected      
    execvp(prgname1[0], p);
    cerr << "execlp 1 failed" << endl;
    cid2 = fork();
}
// 2nd child process reads from the pipe and executes
else if (cid2 == 0) {
    char **p = prgname2;
    close(0);   // closes stdin
    dup(pfd[0]);    // connects pipe input to stdin
    close(pfd[0]);  // closes pipe input as pipe is connected
    close(pfd[1]);  // closes pipe output as it is not needed
    execvp(prgname2[0], p);
    cerr << "execlp 2 failed" << endl;
}
else {
    sleep(1);
    waitpid(cid1, NULL, 0);
    waitpid(cid2, NULL, 0);
    cout << "Program successfully completed" << endl;
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`argv[1]` gives you the first argument on the command line - not the entire command line.  If you want the full list of command line arguments passed into the process, you will need to append `argv[1]`, `argv[2]`, ..., `argv[argc - 1]` together with a space between each.

Additionally, when you process it, you are setting the pointer for your `prgname1[index]` to `command`, so every time you set a given character pointer, they are all pointing to the same location (hence, they are all the same value).  You need to allocate space for each element in `prgname1` and copy `command` into it (using `strncpy`).  Alternatively, using `std::string` and `std::vector` eliminates much of your current code.